# Como sumar en un Select Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

tengo este código

```
$lproductos = $product_sale_data::where('sale_id', '=', $slid)->select('net_unit_price as valor_unitario', 'extra as valor_extra')->get()->toArray();
```

Lo que quisiera es poder agregar un valor suma de net_unit_price y extra.

En PHP y Mysql uso algo como (net_unit_price + extra) as 'suma total', pero en laravel no se como lograrlo.

Answer (score 0):

Para sumar dos columnas no existe una funcionalidad en Eloquent, por lo que la mejor opción es utilizar una consulta *raw* o directamente en el lenguaje del motor, para ello se utiliza el facade DB y su método raw:

```
$lproductos = $product_sale_data::whereSaleId($slid)
                  ->select(DB::raw("
                      net_unit_price as valor_unitario,
                      extra as valor_extra,
                      (net_unit_price + extra) as suma_total   
                  ")
                  ->get()
                  ->toArray();
```

No olvides incluir el facade:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Db;
```